# ImportError: No module named builtins with PyHive using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, hive, pyhive

I'm trying to get PyHive working on a Windows 10 (64-bit) machine with Python 2.7.14.

The machine is secured to the point of it not having Internet access, but I can push files to it.

I have pushed PyHive-0.5.1, future-0.9.0, and thrift-0.11.0 (.tar.gz files) to the machine, and run "python setup.py build" and "python setup.py install" on each of them.

When I try a small test program that just tries to "from pyhive import hive" I get "ImportError: No module named builtins".

Upgrading to Python 3 is not a viable option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a newer version of future, future-0.16.0 which seems to have resolved the issue.